# Triangle to Quad produces disconnected triangles

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

Using the Triangle To Quad option on this mesh produces a bunch of disconnected triangles, like in the photo.

[image]

What is the easiest way to remove these so that they are replaced by quads?

Comment: What do you mean by "disconnected"?

Comment: In this very situation, it may be easier to delete all the faces first, then fill with `Ctrl`+`F` > *Grid Fill*. In a more complicated case, it can be done by hand, filling Ngon and cutting it with `J`.

Answer (score 1):

From that exact view (all those exact faces selected):

- Hit <kbd>X</kbd>, then *faces* to delete the mess you have.
- In edge mode,<kbd>Alt</kbd>+*Right Click* an edge, to select the loop around the hole.
- Hit <kbd>F</kbd> to fill with an ngon.
- Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to *Triangulate*.
- Then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to do a *Triangle to Quad*

EDIT:

Mr Zak's suggestion to use *Grid Fill* greatly improves this answer by reducing the last three steps to just one:

- Hit <kbd>X</kbd>, then *faces* to delete the mess you have.
- In edge mode,<kbd>Alt</kbd>+*Right Click* an edge, to select the loop around the hole.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then *Grid Fill*